# Variable Path Param for GET request in Jmeter

Tags: api, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm testing a GET request using Jmeter, this request has path parameter:

```
rest/V1/autobusca/marketplace/product/:productSku
```

I'm trying to send the parameter in two different locations

1. Send Parameters With the Request
2. And I insert a "User Parameters" as productSku and the value.

I noticed the code response is 200, but the body response is "[]", but when I send it using Postman the response body has a lot of information.

If I change the path in the request like this:

```
rest/V1/autobusca/marketplace/product/${productSku}
```

I noticed the code response is 404. Can you help me?

Comment: Is the response JSON? did you add a Content-Type Header in JMeter?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, it is and I inserted a Content-Type (application/json) in the Header Manager. =(

Answer (score 0):

Use "//" instead of "/".

Correct URL will be : `rest/V1/autobusca/marketplace/product//${productSku}`